# One file at multiple location in windows

Tags: powershell, cmd, junction

Is it possible to have one file in two or more locations (not copy, but same file)?

In workplace, depending on department, we have different shares, and we sometimes need same files (informations in excel). That file need to be accessible in all shares, and if someone edit that file, other in different share folder need to see that changes.
I think this is possible with junctions links, or something similar.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link

Comment: How are you going to deal with concurrent access?

Comment: How about storing the files in a Sharepoint document library? Any version control system would do, but Sharepoint is often familiar solution among non-technical business users.